# multiple drillthrough events in one report ssrs

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, report, drillthrough

I have a main report linked to two subreports, my problem is I can only access one of the reports using drillthrough event, when I try to use an if statement it no longer recognize the data source, I used a "go to url" action to link to the other report. It solved the problem but is not what I really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Go to Report** option by selecting the required parameters if any.